# Passing info from one console application to another using Arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I am not sure why this does not work. I have two applications one is the main application the second is called upon when needed to perform a task. to simplify I am taking out all the other code as I just need help with this one task

Console Application 1

```
  static void Main()
        {
           
            ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startinfo.FileName = @"C:\ConsoleApp2.application";
 
            startinfo.Arguments = "DateRange ClinetID PhoneNo";
            Process.Start(startinfo);
}
```

Console Application 2

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{

    class Program
    {
      
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Received the following arguments:\n" + args.Length);

            for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"[{i}] = {args[i]}");
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();
         }
     }
```

When I run this code the second application will open fine, however, the args.length is always 0. Any help would be great.

Comment: Is the tag visual-studio-2010 accurate? If so I'd recommend using a more recent version. Have you tried sending only one argument to see if its received? There may be issues with spaces in the argument list. I have successfully passed multiple arguments in the path separating them with a semicolon, then parsing them out in the second console app.

Comment: Was not able to reproduce. Also `.application` is an interesting extnsion.

Comment: visual-studio-2010 was an accident - Tried with and with out spaces both did not work.

Comment: Is there any update in this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be in some misunderstanding, are you sure it's not `.exe`?

Two .Net Framework 4.8 Console Apps were created in the vs 2022 community, which can run correctly as shown in the figure.

If you have questions, please comment below.

[image]